# Mapping folder inside parent folder

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Hey guys i have to map folder inside the parent folder . I have the responseJson from backend where workspace_id is the child folder and division_id is the parent folder in which child folder i.e workpace_id has to be mapped each i'm unable to find a way out.. How can i do this in react

**Response Json**

```
{"workspace_id":"s0OQmSi","workspace_name":"my divisions6","userid":"t863060h","division_id":"EOS0dJV"},
{"workspace_id":"VwskYP2","workspace_name":"my divisions5","userid":"t863060h","division_id":"EOS0dJV"}, 
{"workspace_id":"TXkjKxx","workspace_name":"my divisions4","userid":"t863060h","division_id":"EOS0dJV"}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What does map folder inside parent folder mean? Is this supposed to render something?

Comment: @xDreamCoding basically the division_id and the workspace_id are workspaces(kind of folders) which contains worksheets(basically excel files) if response does not have division_id (i.e if division_id is null ) then workspace_id is a workspace but if division_id is not null the workspace_id is a subWorkspace so basically i want to create a folder system with level 1 hierarchy i.e workspace->subWorkspace->worksheet i have data from backend how do i do it in react